# Python-To Extract Data from Text file using Regex using python script

Tags: python, regex

i want to Extract firm name(Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd.) from my text file that are present in next line after Firm name. i have extract some data by my code but i am not able to extact firm name because i am new in python or python regex

```
import re
hand = open(r'C:\Users\sachin.s\Downloads\wordFile_Billing_PrintDocument_7528cc93-3644-4e38-a7b3-10f721fa2049.txt')
copy=False
for line in hand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if re.search('Order Number\S*: [0-9.]+', line):
        print(line)
    if re.search('Invoice No\S*: [0-9.]+', line):
        print(line)
    if re.search('Invoice Date\S*: [0-9.]+', line):
        print(line)
    if re.search('PO No\S*: [0-9.]+', line):
        print(line)
```

Firm Name: Address:
Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd.
Regd Office: 6th Floor, DLF Centre, Sansad Marg, New Delhi-110001

SAMSUNG INDIA ELECTRONICS PVT LTD, MEDCHAL MANDAL HYDERABAD

RANGA REDDY DISTRICT HYDERABAD TELANGANA 501401
Phone: 1234567
Fax No:
Branch: S5S2 - [SIEL]HYDERABAD
Order Number: 1403543436
Currency: INR
Invoice No: 36S2I0030874
Invoice Date: 15.12.2018
PI No: 5929947652

Comment: post few lines of toy `txt` data

Comment: Can you provide content of you file?

Comment: Firm Name: Address:
Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd.
Regd Office: 6th Floor, DLF Centre, Sansad Marg, New Delhi-110001

Comment: @sachin sharma add few more lines before and after text you posted. Add this to you question

Comment: after Firm name: Address: the next text is in new line upto LTD. after that again the data is in new line i want to extract only(Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd)

Comment: how to add text file please guide me then so i can add my text file

Comment: @sachinsharma copy paste text from file after question edit then mark added text and pres `ctrl +k`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use regex:

```
import re

data = """
Firm Name: Address:
Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd.
Regd Office: 6th Floor, DLF Centre, Sansad Marg, New Delhi-110001

SAMSUNG INDIA ELECTRONICS PVT LTD, MEDCHAL MANDAL HYDERABAD

RANGA REDDY DISTRICT HYDERABAD TELANGANA 501401 Phone: 1234567 Fax No: Branch: S5S2 - [SIEL]HYDERABAD
Order Number: 1403543436
Currency: INR
Invoice No: 36S2I0030874
Invoice Date: 15.12.2018
PI No: 5929947652
"""

result = re.findall('Address:(.*)Regd', data, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
 Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd.
```

Comment: hi @zaraki but this regex works only this file. i have many text file Firm  Name: Address: is same  but in place of Regd any text is available then this regex is fail

Comment: my text format Firm Name: Address: new line   Samsung India Electronics Pvt. Ltd. new line       Regd Office: 6th Floor, DLF Centre, Sansad Marg, New Delhi-110001'

Comment: @sachinsharma then post more examples of text

Comment: please provide yor email i will send the text file

Comment: i update the text file format please see the format and thanks for giving your time

Comment: @sachinsharma post another example or link to you full text

Comment: all text file are same format just give the regex for attacehed text and i check that regex

Comment: Firm Name is same for all the text file only difference in invoce no.,invoice date etc

Comment: @sachinsharma don't know what you mean by that ... show more examples or 
or make yourself

Comment: thanks bro it is working but when i append your code in my code it is not print can you guide me i can read the text file or it is working with open file variable

Comment: it throuhg an error  File "c:/Users/sachin.s/Desktop/python_regex.py", line 26, in <module>
    result = re.findall('Address:(.*)Regd', contents, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @sachinsharma You are reading line by line with `for line in hand:`. You should use `contents = hand.read()` and then use the regex.

Comment: if i am using your regex code inside it doesn't work but outside loop it works by using same step you told me as above comment